# Sharp things on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security

Can I bring my cuticle cutters and nail file? If yes how should I pack it and in which bag?

Comment: What countries are you flying through?

Comment: I am going  to Mexico

Comment: In which country are you boarding your flight, then? That's where you will go through airport security.

Answer (score 4):

The answer may depend on which airport(s) you’re travelling through. According to the TSA website https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all nail files are allowed in carry on and checked baggage, but cuticle cutters don’t appear to be listed. Personally I’d always pack such items in checked baggage (or leave them at home when I only have carry on). Despite what any rules might say, if you put them in your carry on bag there’s always a chance they’ll be confiscated at security.